# How to update an object with keys from another object in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

i am newcomer to typescript and have a following problem

I have an object of type `Man` with set of keys

```
type Man = { name: string; surname: string; age: number }
type ManKey = keyof Man

const johnSmith: Man = { name: 'John', surname: 'Smith', age: 99 }
```

now i have an object with arbitrary properties, some of them can intersect with `Man`'s keys, then we should use their values to update johnSmith values. For instance:

```
const newProps = { religion: 'hindu', age: 30 }
```

in this example `age` should be recognized as `Man`'s property and `30` should be written to `johnSmith` variable. Something like this (such code of course doesn't work)

```
for (let key in newProps) 
  if (key instanceof ManKey)
    johnSmith[key] = newProps[key]
```

Thanks in advance

PS sandbox with example
https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-ardinghelli-db6kv?file=/src/App.tsx:0-478

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuo're close, but you shoul duse `key in johnSmith` instead of `key instanceof ManKey`:

```js
for (const key in newProps) {
    if (key in johnSmith) {
        johnSmith[key] = newProps[key];
    }
}
```

EDIT: It appears that [typescript still suffers from the inability to infer `for...in` types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32811), so for now you'll have to do the ugly method of casting the key:

```js
for (let key in newProps) {
  if (key in johnSmith) {
    let castKey = key as (keyof typeof newProps & keyof typeof johnSmith);
    johnSmith[castKey] = newProps[castKey];
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not so easy, for both sides of assignment i get ts errors. For a first one "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Man'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Man'

Comment: sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-ardinghelli-db6kv?file=/src/App.tsx:0-478

Comment: @DmitryReutov I've updated my answer with some working code.

Comment: Looks quite tricky since i'm not used to it. Thanks!

Comment: but if there are ways to check if some string is instance of keyof someobj in case if i have only type without its instance and can not use `str in ob` expression?j

Comment: No, that is [something that typescript never aims to do](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) (see non-goal #5). The typesystem should never influence the behavior of the running program (the keys in a type should not be able to influence a `keyof` call).